# Will upgrading Office from 2003 to 2007 break VB programs which use Excel through the COM interop?

Tags: vb.net, excel, com, interop

Assume all traces of Office 2003 will be removed from the computer.

UPDATE:

I understand that I will still be able to use .xls files. I'm asking about automating Excel through the COM interop from outside Excel. When I add a reference to Excel to a VB project, it gives me a different version of the dll for different versions of Excel. If a program was compiled with a reference to Office 2003's dll, will it need to be recompiled for Office 2007? Will the code need to be updated to use the new dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have no problem with your code breaking. In my past experiences, even though I referenced old versions of the Interop Assemblies, the newer version of Excel has been able to handle the calls.

Now the same can't be said for trying to use a newer version of the Interop Assemblies with an older version of Excel...

Answer (score 0):

It would be very surprising if there were many breaking changes between the versions. As I understand it, Microsoft has a number of customers using Office, and they wouldn't like a large number of breaking changes.

In my opinion, the above is actually a valid way of analyzing many questions of this type: "Could *x* possibly happen" is aproximately equivalent to "what would happen to Microsoft if they did *x*". If the answer is "something really bad would happen", then chances are that Microsoft figured that out ahead of time.

Of course, this doesn't work 100%. "Could Microsoft ever remove Web Application Projects from Visual Studio 2005" is a counterexample.